# Find how much alcohol in grams is in this margarita recipe

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose person A is an avid margarita drinker and a tequila aficionado, and he decides to have a Don Julio anejo margarita with a splash of OJ. If his margarita is made by the following recipe, how many grams of alcohol will that person consume?

$2.5$ oz. of Don Julio (80 proof)

$1/2$ oz. of lime juice

$1/2$ oz. of Hiram walker triple sec (60 proof)

$4$ oz. of sour mix.

$1/2$ oz. of OJ

I do have the following conversion fomulas

\begin{align}
1 \text{%} \, \, \, \text{alcohol by vol.} &= 2 \, \, \, \textrm{proof} \\
1 \, \, \, \text{fl. oz.} &= 29.6 \, \, \, \text{mL} \\
\text{density of ethanol (alcohol)} &= 0.789 \, \, \, \text{g/mL}
\end{align}

Initially, I thought the only relevant information was the sum $s$ of the ounces containing alcohol, which would then have $140$ proof:

$$s = 3.0 \, \, \, \text{fl. oz.} = 140 \, \, \, \text{proof}$$

If we convert the $140$ proof into its alcohol by volume content, denoted $A$, we have

$$A = 70\text{% alcohol} = 140 \, \, \, \text{proof}$$

Next, I converted the $3.0$ oz. to mL, which I'll denote by $O$,

$$O = 3 \, \, \, \text{fl. oz.} = 88.8 \, \, \, \text{mL}$$

Then I used the third conversion formula from the top to get my $70$% alcohol in grams

$$0.70 \, \, \, \text{alcohol} = \frac{0.70*88.8}{88.8} (0.789) \, \, \, \text{g\mL} \approx. 49.04 \, \, \, \text{g\mL}$$

Of course, this answer is not correct, and I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why add the concentrations?

Comment: If I mix something that is 80 proof (40% alcohol) and something that is 60 proof (30% alcohol), does it make sense to get a mixture that is 140 proof (70% alcohol)?!

Comment: Your answer is expressed in $g/mL$ but the question asks for grams.  It can't be right.

Answer (score 3):

First, let us determine the *volume* of alcohol in the mix (where I'm going to be lazy and use "oz" for fluid ounces):

The Don Julio is 80 proof, which means that 40% of the 2.5 oz of tequila are alcohol.  Multiplying these, we get
$$ 2.5\text{ oz} \cdot 0.40 = 1 \text{ oz}, $$
thus we get 1 oz of alcohol from the tequila.

Similarly, we get
$$ 0.5 \text{ oz} \cdot 0.30 = 0.15\text{ oz}$$
of alcohol from the orange liqueur (though why you would use Triple Sec, rather than something nice the Cointreau is beyond me; I'm not judging, though).  At any rate, the drink then contains a total of 1.15 oz of alcohol.

Now that we know the volume of alcohol in the drink, we can use the conversion formulae you give to get a mass.  Applying the conversions, we get
$$ 1.15 \text{ oz} \cdot \frac{29.6 \text{ mL}}{\text{oz}} \cdot \frac{0.789\text{ g}}{\text{mL}} \approx 26.9 \text{ g}$$
of alcohol.  Note how the units "upstairs" cancel the units "downstairs", leaving us with only gram

Comment: Well done, including the fact that proof corresponds to alcohol per volume, not per mass.

Comment: The answer says $26.86 \, \, \, \text{g alcohol}$, so I'm not sure what the alcohol part means. At any rate, how would I take the solution that you have and shift the decimal over to the right without changing the units?

Comment: The solution I get is 2.685756 grams of alcohol, which is one tenth of the answer you were supposed to get.  Hence either I missed a factor of 10 somewhere (though I don't see it), one of your conversion factors is off by a factor of 10, or the book is wrong.  Before blindly moving decimal points around, maybe check the work---see if you can follow all of my steps and derive the same answer, or find my error (and if you find one, please let me know).

Comment: I think your $2.96$ should be a $29.6$

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire I am entirely willing to believe that.  Can you please tell me where the error in my computation is?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Well, from her conversion formulas, $1 \, \text{oz.} = 29.6 \, \text{mL}$.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire Ah!  There it is!  Thank you!  Give me a moment to correct it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson no problem!

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire Also, I see now I really should have figured it out from your comment last night.  I just read 29.6 (the correct conversion factor) as 26.9 (the answer that I was supposed to have arrived at).  I thought you were being smart-alecky.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @XanderHenderson hahaha Yeah, Ivan see that. No worries